# sharepoint REST API - share document

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

Does anyone knows how to use REST API to share a document in sharepoint to someone inside the same organization and external user ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below rest api endpoint to share document in SharePoint : `/_api/SP.Sharing.DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo`

Please refer to this blog for more: http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2014/09/sharing-documents-with-sharepoint-rest.html